# Fortran - Is a goto outside the loop considered the end of the loop too?

Tags: fortran

Below you can see that based on the if statement a jump is either going to be made to label 305 or label 320. When the jump to the 305 is made there is a continue statement so the loop is ended but when the jump to 320 is taken there is no continue statement so does this mean it is still in the loop?

```
DO 305 I = 1,L
           IF (ICHAR(D(I)) - ICHAR("-")) 305,320,305
305    CONTINUE
       GO TO 390
320    WRITE (*,*) D(1:L)
```

Comment: Is your confusion with what `continue` means? That is, do you understand the range of the loop?  The title makes me think you do, but then the text seems different.

Comment: No, i know when continue means the end of the loop. What is confusing me is that when we jump from the if statment to label 320 we skip the continue so does this mean we are still in the loop or is the loop ended?

Comment: `continue` isn't special in signifying the end of the loop.  It's the label (`305` here) that matters.  `305 continue` could just as easily be `305 ppppp=0.` except that the former has no effect.  Either way `320` is not in the range.

Comment: Oh ok, so that means in the case above both the jump statements 'exit' the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The range of the `do` construct is the (arithmetic) `if` statement and the labelled `continue`.  After execution of the `continue` statement the next iteration (if there is one) of the loop starts.

`continue` isn't itself very special: it is an allowed statement terminating the loop construct (the `if` statement isn't allowed to terminate it) which has no other effect, but nearly any other executable statement would be allowed to fill that termination role.  In particular, `continue` doesn't mean "start the next iteration of whichever loop we're in".

So: jumping to the statement labelled `305` remains inside the loop construct; jumping to that labelled `320` leaves the loop construct, and no `continue` will get us back inside it.  In this latter case the loop is terminated and `i` retains the value it had at the jump.

[You've seen in an answer to a closely related question a "modern" version of this block of code.]

Comment: I think i understand now, so if it is the first iteration (or anything other that the last iteration ) of the loop the jump to the continue statement just means now the next iteration is going to take place. But in the final iteration the jump to the continue will exit the loop. Is what i just said what would occur?

Comment: Essentially.  There will be `L` iterations of the loop (unless we jump to `320`).  After the `L`-th execution of `305 continue` we move on to `go to 390`.  Do note (it's important in cases where it isn't `continue`), though, that the iteration starts _after_ the statement labelled `305` is executed.

Comment: I think one source of confusion may be the way C and all descendant languages adopted the `continue` statement as a keyword which means the same as Fortran's `cycle`. That adoption was ironically caused by the usage of `continue` in Fortran as a loop delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can modernize this

```
DO 305 I = 1,L
           IF (ICHAR(D(I)) - ICHAR("-")) 305,320,305
305    CONTINUE
       GO TO 390
320    WRITE (*,*) D(1:L)
390    CONTINUE
```

with

```
DO I=1,L
    IF( ICHAR(D(I))==ICHAR("-") ) THEN
        WRITE (*,*) D(1:L)
        EXIT
    END IF
END DO
```

The [`EXIT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/g77/CYCLE-and-EXIT.html) command quits the inner DO loop and the `CYCLE` command continues the loop on the next iteration.

Comment: Or `if(any(...)) write ...`.

Comment: Ok i just want to clarify, so the goto 390 is only executed when the loop has gone around L times and a jump to 320 has not been made right?